# .htaccess Redirect If Not Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have an `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite to redirect URLs from the old website to the new webpage equivalents. The new site can be viewed at `www.eastwood-whelpton.co.uk` (which only works in HTML5 browsers right now).

So far, I have got this working by making lots of `Redirect Permanent` statements to translate each of the old pages to a place in the new site.

This has worked until I've needed to create a subdomain for the old website (which I need to keep). Before, it was just in the folder `/old/`, but Google still crawls it despite not being allowed from Robots.txt. To fix this, I've put it in the subdomain 'old'.

Problem now is, accessing a page such as `old.eastwood-whelpton.co.uk/about.htm` will still try to redirect to `old.eastwood-whelpton.co.uk/about/about.php` - which is on the new site.

Here's a snippet of my HTACCESS file. All I need is to redirect old 'www' pages, but not old pages in the 'old' subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eastwood-whelpton [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

Redirect permanent /index.htm /index.php
Redirect permanent /index.html /index.php

Redirect permanent /yachthire.htm /holidays/sailingholidays.php
Redirect permanent /yachts.htm /about/thefleet.php
Redirect permanent /handover.htm /training/handover.php
Redirect permanent /holiday.htm /holidays/familyholidays.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is a directive from [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_alias.html)

Do not mix them! Your `Redirect` directive will execute in-spite of Whatever `RewriteRule` you have.

Do this instead:

I have changed your `Redirects` to `RewriteRule` and tweaked them a bit. Have added,

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^ - [L]

This will not redirect any of your `old` site URLs.

Here is the whole :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^eastwood-whelpton [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

ReWriteRule index\.html? /index.php [L,R=301]
ReWriteRule yachthire\.htm /holidays/sailingholidays.php [L,R=301]
ReWriteRule yachts\.htm /about/thefleet.php [L,R=301]
ReWriteRule (handover)\.htm /training/$1.php [L,R=301]
ReWriteRule (holiday)\.htm /holidays/family$1s.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Excellent. It's still a bit patchy, probably from caching and whatnot - only /yachts.htm redirect works properly for the minute, but I think the RewriteRule ^ - [L] is the key to the puzzle. I'll choose this as the answer once I get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @CJxD clear your browser cache once. And then try. Just in case Restart your Apache as well.

Comment: Okay, I still cant get it to work. The only one that responds properly is the /yachts\.htm line.

Comment: @CJxD I had updated The answer a while ago.. Had removed every `/` at the beginning.

Comment: @CJxD from [rewriterule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule): `In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).`

Comment: Okay, that seems to work much better. Still a couple of glitches from caches, but I've run out of alternate browsers now. I'll finish off the rest of the redirects and see how it goes.

Comment: Yep, perfect. It also made it trivial for redirecting the booking form: `RewriteRule images/Booking\sForm\s\d+\.pdf /holidays/booking-form.pdf [R=301,L]`